# How to bring Front Devexpress BarItem on RibbonForm

Tags: c#, devexpress, dock

I'm using DevExpress `barItem` on my `RibbonForm`. I deleted Ribbon component and I want to have `barItem` instead of `Ribbon`. But have interesting view. I'm adding 2 diffrent pictures. I think they can tell all problems. 
How can I put `barItem` under `RibbonForm`?
**Desing Time**
[image]

**Run Time**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use `XtraForm` instead of `RibbonForm`?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes can use it. but I used RibbonForm because I want to application button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BarManager.Form`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarManager_Formtopic) property. Just add the `PanelControl` into your `RibbonForm` and set `BarManager.Form` property to this panel.
Here is the result:

[image]